# После обновления Visual Studio 2015 update 1 не могу писать русскими буквами

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Обновился, и теперь, когда набираю ИМЕННО В РЕДАКТОРЕ русской раскладкой, лезут разные сиволы и цифры, вместо русских букв. Как исправить?
[image: Сабж]

В настройках например, могу писать русскими. Если скопировать откуда нибудь текст и вставить в редакторе, то всё тоже будет отображаться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправил проблему отключив все расширения. Видимо после апдейта какое то из них покарёжило, и оно заставило студию так страдать.

Answer (score 0):

Откатить обнову и попробовать переустановить ( при установке обновления VS делает контрольную точку восстановления системы )

PS у 15-ой пока ещё много всяких "глюков" которые проявляются от случая к случаю. На самые распространённые из них реально найти фиксы в блоге разработчиков. Но на такой глюк скорее всего фиксов нет.